# Gas Water Heating

Tags: water-heater

When I turn on a cold water tap including the garden hose my instantaneous gas water heater starts up.I have turned the hot water valve off at heater and checked that ALL hot water taps have no flow so its not a crossover.

Comment: What make and model is your hot water heater?

Comment: it is a Rheem Integrity 24  Model Noi 871024NF-B